# Why does isDot() fail on me? (PHP)

Tags: php, iterator

I'm finalizing a code segment that lists the files in a directory. I have no problems listing the files in a directory but for some reason I can get the isDot() method to work to make sure the file isn't a "." or ".." . The following below results in this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method SplFileInfo::isDot() in ....
```

Before I switched over to using the Recursive Iterator I was using the Directory Iterator and it worked fine. Is there anything wrong with the code below? It should work.

```
$files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($pathToFolder));

//if there is a subdirectory it makes sure the proper extension is passed
foreach($files as $name => $file){      

            if (!$file->isDot()) {    //this is where it shuts me down          

            $realfile = str_replace($pathToFolder, "", $file);
            $url = getDownloadLink($folderID, $realfile);
        $fileArray[] = $url;            

        }       
}
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This is, because [`DirectoryIterator::current()`](http://php.net/directoryiterator.current) (the method, that is call within a `foreach`-loop) returns an object, which is itself of type `DirectoryIterator`. `FileSystemIterator` (that `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` extends) returns an object of `SplFileInfo` be default. You can influence, what is return, via [flags](http://php.net/manual/class.filesystemiterator.php#filesystemiterator.constants)

```
$files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
  new RecursiveDirectoryIterator(
    $pathToFolder,
    FilesystemIterator::KEY_AS_PATHNAME | FilesystemIterator::CURRENT_AS_SELF));
```

But in your case, you don't need to test, if an item is a dot-file. Just set `FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS` and they will not appear at all. Note, that this is also the [default behavior](http://php.net/filesystemiterator.construct).

Comment: Don't know if it was changed, but `FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS` is not default for RecursiveDirectoryIterator anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer is excellent, but for a different approach you can set the
`SKIP_DOTS` flag:

```
<?php

$o_dir = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($pathToFolder);
$o_dir->setFlags(RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
$o_iter = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($o_dir);

foreach ($o_iter as $o_info) {
   echo $o_info->getPathname(), "\n";
}
```

https://php.net/filesystemiterator.setflags