# Directory iterator and recursive directory iterator

Tags: php, recursion, iterator

I had to list all files and folders in a directory:

```
            $images = array();
            $dirs   = array();

            $dir = new DirectoryIterator($upload_dir_real);

             foreach ($dir as $file) {
               if ($file->isDot()) {
                    continue;
                }

                if ($file->isDir()) {
                    // dir
                    $scanned_dirs[] = $file->getPath();
                      continue;
                } else {
                    // file

                    //echo $file->getFilename() . "<br>\n";//DEBUG
                    $realfile =  $file->getFilename() . "<br>\n";
                    $realpath = $file->getPathname();
                    echo realpath($realfile);//DEBUG
                    $file->getFilename();
                    $images[] = realpath( $realpath );
                }

             }
```

This works fine (no errors) but of course counted only the root, so I tried recursive:

```
            $images = array();
            $dirs   = array();
$dir = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($upload_dir_real);

             foreach ($dir as $file) {
               if ($file->isDot()) {
                    continue;
                }

                if ($file->isDir()) {
                    // dir
                    $scanned_dirs[] = $file->getsubPath();
                      continue;
                } else {
                    // file

                    //echo $file->getFilename() . "<br>\n"; //DEBUG
                    $realfile =  $file->getsubFilename() . "<br>\n";
                    $realpath = $file->getsubPathname();
                    echo realpath($realfile);//DEBUG
                    $file->getFilename();
                    $images[] = realpath( $realpath );
                }

             }
```

Basically, I changed the `getPath();` with `getsubPath()` (and equivalent). The problem is that it give me an error:

> `Fatal error: Call to undefined method SplFileInfo::isDot() in blah blah path`

so I searched a while and found this:

[Why does isDot() fail on me? (PHP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6337810/why-does-isdot-fail-on-me-php)

This is basically the same problem, but when I try, I get this error:

> `Fatal error: Class 'FilesystemIterator' not found in in blah blah path`

Questions:

1 - why is the method described in the other accepted answer not working for me?
2 - in that same answer, what is the following code:

```
new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
  new RecursiveDirectoryIterator(
    $pathToFolder,
    FilesystemIterator::KEY_AS_PATHNAME | FilesystemIterator::CURRENT_AS_SELF));
```

This actually calls `RecursiveIteratorIterator` twice? I mean, if it is recursive, it can not be recursive twice :-)

2b - how come `FilesystemIterator` is not found, even if the PHP manual states (to my understanding) that it is a part of what the recursive iterator is built upon?

(Those questions are because I want to understand better, not to just copy and paste answers).

3 - is there a better way to list all folders and files cross platform?

Comment: `FilesystemIterator` was introduced in PHP 5.3, and the API documentation just represents the current state of `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` being based upon it. In your last snippet you aren't using RII twice, you have one RII and one RDI.

Comment: What version of PHP are you using

Comment: ooh .. I missed that RII and RDI - thanks,  (the php version is also explained - i use 5.2.9) but still - how can I use the is_dot or equivalent ?? how to make this function work ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- 1 - why is the method described in the other accepted answer not working for me ??`

As far as i can tell . the code works perfectly but your implementation is wrong you are using the following

Code

```
   $dir = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($upload_dir_real);
```

Instead of

```
    $dir = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($upload_dir_real));
```

- In that same answer actually calls RecursiveIteratorIterator twice ?? I mean, if it is recursive , it can not be recursive twice ... :-))

No it does not its different

```
RecursiveIteratorIterator != RecursiveDirectoryIterator != FilesystemIterator
            ^                             ^
```

- how come FilesystemIterator is not found , even if the php manual states (to my understanding) that it is a part of what the recursive iterator is built upon??

You already answered that your self in your comment you are using PHP version `5.2.9` which is no longer supported or recommended

- 3 - Is there a better way to list all folder and files cross platform ??

Since that is resolved all you need is `FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS` you don't have to call `$file->isDot()`

Example

```
$fullPath = __DIR__;
$dirs = $files = array();

$directory = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($fullPath, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator($directory, RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST) as $path ) {
    $path->isDir() ? $dirs[] = $path->__toString() : $files[] = realpath($path->__toString());
}

var_dump($files, $dirs);
```

Comment: ok - thanks (again... :-) ) but it gives me the same error `Fatal error: Class 'FilesystemIterator' not found ` - is there some other method i can use to avoid the same error on my php version ??

Comment: Just a quick question .. why are you still using a version of php that is no longer supported which is  `5.2.9`

Comment: well- no good answer to that question - my local DEV server is just what it is . I never had any problems with that (i´m quite a novice) but maybe it is time to upgrade both my skills and my server at once ...

Comment: the reason for the low php version is mainly because of compatibility support . I develop with wordpress (that still supports  `5.2.4` by it´s codex page ) and I have encountered a lot of servers that this version `(5.2.9 is)` still installed . it would still be nice to know if it is possible to do recursive iterator in `php<5.3`

Answer (score 1):

Here is another method, utilizing `setFlags`:

```
<?php

$o_dir = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('.');
$o_dir->setFlags(RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
$o_iter = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($o_dir);

foreach ($o_iter as $o_info) {
   echo $o_info->getPathname(), "\n";
}
```

https://php.net/filesystemiterator.setflags